# KWin and java transparency

Tags: java, linux, transparency, kde-plasma

I want to have transparent JWindow but i failed on my machine which have archlinux + kde installed. I found out that java checks this variable _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY on system level to know if transparency is supported on the system. Problem is that it seems that KWin (kde composite manager) does not report that variable. I tried it with compiz and on xfce and everything works. How can I make transparency work on KWin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with custom JWindow (note that it works without this on windows and osx) :

```
public class TransparentWindow extends JWindow {

public TransparentWindow(Window owner) {
    this(owner, WindowUtils.getAlphaCompatibleGraphicsConfiguration());
  }

  private TransparentWindow(Window owner, GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration) {
    super(owner, graphicsConfiguration);
  }
....
}
```